# Proof without Jensen

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, proof

In the middle of an argument that I will present to my students I'll have to prove that $E[X^2]\geq E^2[X]$, but I don't want to use Jensen's inequality to do so. Is there any elementary way to go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

It follows from $\mathrm{Var}[X] = \mathrm{E}[X^2] - \mathrm{E}^2[X] \geq 0$.

Comment: +1 This is ideal because it relies on the most basic inequality of all: that squares of (real) numbers are non-negative.  Even schoolchildren readily grasp that!

Comment: (+1) Indeed, this is precisely the example I keep in my head when thinking about Jensen's inequality so that I don't accidentally get the inequality in the wrong direction.

Comment: I do exactly the same "mind trick", cardinal!